# Get email domain name without name before @ and tld

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to get just the domain name from an email address - so if the email address is john@gmail.com I need to grab just the gmail part.

I have the following code that works and returns **gmail** for a john@gmail.com email address but returns **co** for a john@gmail.co.uk email address.

```
$user_register_email = "john@gmail.co.uk";

$domain = preg_replace( '!^.+?@(.+?)$!', '$1', $user_register_email );
$domain = explode('.', $domain);
$domain = array_reverse($domain);
$domain = "$domain[1]";

echo $domain;
```

Can anyone tell me how I amend the above code so it will also work for gmail.co.uk addresses please?

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$user_register_email = "john@gmail.co.uk";

$domain = explode('@', $user_register_email);
$domain = explode('.', $domain[1]);
echo $domain[0];
```

You can use 2 explodes

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate the domain part (string after the @) in this way

```
$mystring = substr(user_register_email ,strpos($user_register_email , '@') +1, 255);
```

and the perform the explode

Answer (score 0):

`explode` and `reverse` functions on the array are not necessary, `preg_replace` is fine by itself:

```
$domain = preg_replace( '!^.+?([^@]+)$!', '$1', $user_register_email );
```

**Output:**

```
gmail.co.uk
```